# Determing if HTML item has a class with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to determine if a li item has the class .corsa-yes. If yes I would like to append to an array  'STATUS': "active". The data is scraped from [this website](https://www.medmargroup.it)
I've tried the following code but I get

```
if "corsa-yes" in next_li.get("class"):
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Here is my code

```
medmar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('li.tratta'))
departure_time = []
    for li in medmar_live_departures_table:
        next_li = li.find_next_sibling("li")
        while next_li and next_li.get("data-toggle"):
            departure_time.append(next_li.strong.text)
            next_li = next_li.find_next_sibling("li")
        medmar_live_departures_data.append({
              'ROUTE' : li.text,
              'DEPARTURE TIME' : departure_time,
        })
             if "corsa-yes" in next_li.get("class"):
                medmar_live_departures_data.append({
                       'STATUS': "active" 
                })
```

Comment: Could you do try: if “cords-yes” in ....: rest of code.   except: pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

is because the element has `no class`, you need first to check if it exist or compare with the array

```
if next_li.get("class") == ["corsa-yes"]:
# or check it first
if next_li.get("class") and "corsa-yes" in next_li.get("class"):
```

I change`'STATUS': "active"` to `'ACTIVE_TIME': '10:35'` and complete code

```
departure_time = []
active_time = None
for li in medmar_live_departures_table:
    next_li = li.find_next_sibling("li")
    while next_li and next_li.get("data-toggle"):
        if next_li.get("class") == ["corsa-yes"]:
            active_time = next_li.strong.text
        departure_time.append(next_li.strong.text)
        next_li = next_li.find_next_sibling("li")
    medmar_live_departures_data.append({
          'ROUTE' : li.text,
          'ACTIVE_TIME' : active_time,
          'DEPARTURE TIME' : departure_time
    })
    departure_time = []
```

Result

```
[
  {'ROUTE': 'ISCHIA » PROCIDA', 'ACTIVE_TIME': '10:35', 'DEPARTURE TIME': ['06:25', '10:35']},
  {'ROUTE': 'PROCIDA » NAPOLI', 'ACTIVE_TIME': '07:05', 'DEPARTURE TIME': ['07:05', '11:15']}
]
```

Comment: Thank you again ;-) and happy New Year!